# CORS error while uploading image on Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload images directly from the browser to the Google Cloud bucket. I am using [gcs-signed-urls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcs-signed-urls) on the backend and followed [this](https://github.com/sfarthin/nodejs-google-cloud-storage/blob/master/example/form.ejs) example.

Here is my Form upload which is working fine.

```
<form action={"https://" +this.state.imageForm.bucket +".storage.googleapis.com"}  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value={this.state.imageForm.key}></input>
<input type="hidden" name="bucket" value={this.state.imageForm.bucket}></input>
<input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value={this.state.imageForm.GoogleAccessId}></input>
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value={this.state.imageForm.policy}></input>
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value={this.state.imageForm.signature}></input>
<input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value={this.state.imageForm.contenttype}></input>
<input name="file" type="file"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
```

Now I am trying to turn this into form post request using Axios.

```
 let data = new FormData();
data.append("key",this.state.imageForm.key+ "." + picture[0].type.replace("image/", ""))
data.append("bucket", this.state.imageForm.bucket);
data.append("GoogleAccessId", this.state.imageForm.GoogleAccessId);
data.append("policy", this.state.imageForm.policy);
data.append("Content-Type", 'application/octet-stream');
data.append("file", picture[0]);
console.log("data", data);
let config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  }
}
let result = await axios.post("https://" + this.state.imageForm.bucket + ".storage.googleapis.com",
  data, config)
```

I am getting 2 errors:

1 - CROS error

```
create:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ccc.storage.googleapis.com/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

2- Post request is failing with 400 error with the response.

Here is a snapshot from the developer console.

[image]

I also updated the Cors file for my bucket, here is the config

```
  {
  "origin": [*],
  "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "access-control-allow-origin"],
  "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "PUT", "POST"],
  "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following note in the [API POST method docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object)

> Note: The POST object method does not support [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), except in the case of [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload).

So you can try the [PUT method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object) or doing a [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload) as stated at the docs